# Setting a Flash error message with FormRequest

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-6

I am attempting to set and pass a flash message, when a form validation fails. When the validation passes, I am able to set Flash message in the controller.

I have tried to override the `protected failedValidation()` but I get an error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:50',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:50',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
            'gender' => 'required|in:male,female'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     */
    protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
    {
        Flash::error("Profile could not be saved!");
        // alert()->error('oops ... error');
        return parent::failedValidation($validator);
    } }
```

error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class
>   'App\Http\Requests\Flash' not found

I am setting my view in app.blade.php as follows

```
<div class="flash-message">
                @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
                    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
                        <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div> <!-- end .flash-message -->
```

Comment: tried this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/flash-message-with-formrequest

Comment: It means you did not Import the Flash class into your FormRequest

Comment: @Flash tried it - but getting error. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'Flash' not found

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `use Flash;` in the controller at the top after namespace declaration where you want to use the flash library methods.

Comment: I tried this, but got this error. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'Flash' not found

Comment: would u mind to add all your code and update the question